# How to replace a letter in a data frame?

Tags: regex, r

I have a data frame. I want to search for each letter or symbol.

For example, I would like to the letter "g" and "h". If the letter is in a character string anywhere then assign 1 else 0.

```
code              gh     HI    &*
efhikq&*          0      0     1
efhiku&           0      0     0
DHIfux            0      1     0
DHIJUVXYefhjoq!*  0      1     0
HIfghv(           1      1     0
hiIvg             1      0     0
```

Comment: `as.numeric(grepl('g',dataframe$code))`, etc.

Comment: A generalization of @Thomas's suggestion would be to put your search patterns in a vector and use `sapply`. If the search strings were in a vector named "patterns", something like `sapply(patterns, function(x) as.numeric(grepl(x, code, fixed = TRUE)))` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE, for the more complex version that requires all letters to be present, but in any order:

```
haystack <- c("efhikq&*", "efhiku&", "DHIfux", "DHIJUVXYefhjoq!*", "HIfghv(", "hiIvg")
needle <- c("gh", "HI", "&*")

needle.split <- setNames(strsplit(needle, ""), needle)

`rownames<-`(
  sapply(
    needle.split, 
    function(x) {
      apply(sapply(x, grepl, haystack, fixed=TRUE), 1, all) + 0
} ), haystack)
```

Here we start by breaking up needle into component characters, and then for each character in a set of characters, we run `grepl` against haystack (this is the innermost `sapply`), then we ensure that every character is present by checking all the values for every row of the matrix that that innermost `sapply` produced with `apply` and `all`.  We also convert to 1/0 with the `+ 0` bit (which also preserves matrix structure).  Finally, the outermost `sapply` will repeat this logic for each character group, and stitch back the result, which we add rownames to with the `rownames<-` trick.

This matches the desired output:

```
                 gh HI &*
efhikq&*          0  0  1
efhiku&           0  0  0
DHIfux            0  1  0
DHIJUVXYefhjoq!*  0  1  0
HIfghv(           1  1  0
hiIvg             1  0  0
```

---

OLD VERSION matches all characters:

Here is a solution:

```
`rownames<-`(sapply(needle, grepl, haystack, fixed=TRUE) + 0, haystack)
```

produces:

```
                 gh HI &*
efhikq&*          0  0  1
efhiku&           0  0  0
DHIfux            0  1  0
DHIJUVXYefhjoq!*  0  1  0
HIfghv(           1  1  0
hiIvg             0  0  0
```

This is basically an implementation of what Ananda suggests (I didn't see his comment until after I had finished this), with the added "trick" of using the replacement function `rownames<-` in a non-replacement form to attach the row names.  Here is the data:

```
haystack <- c("efhikq&*", "efhiku&", "DHIfux", "DHIJUVXYefhjoq!*", "HIfghv(", "hiIvg")
needle <- c("gh", "HI", "&*")
```

Comment: I've posted some fun benchmarks [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22131327/1270695) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that should be pretty efficient. It looks pretty messy, but I couldn't think of a nicer alternative to `paste0` here. The basic step is to create regex patterns that look like `"^(?=.*g)(?=.*h)"` along with setting `perl = TRUE` in `grepl`.

```
Specials <- c(".", "|", "(", ")", "[", "{", "^", "$", "*", "+", "?")
Patterns <- strsplit(patterns, "", fixed=TRUE)
out <- vapply(vapply(Patterns, function(x) {
  x <- ifelse(x %in% Specials, paste0("\\", x), x)
  paste0("^", paste0("(?=.*", x, ")", collapse=""))
}, character(1L)), grepl, logical(length(code)),
code, perl = TRUE) * 1
dimnames(out) <- list(code, patterns)
out
#                  gh HI &*
# efhikq&*          0  0  1
# efhiku&           0  0  0
# DHIfux            0  1  0
# DHIJUVXYefhjoq!*  0  1  0
# HIfghv(           1  1  0
# hiIvg             1  0  0
```

---

#### Benchmarks

Compared with @BrodieG's answer, this fares quite well. Here are some benchmarks.

***The functions to benchmark***

```
funBG <- function() {
   needle.split <- setNames(strsplit(needle, ""), needle)
  `rownames<-`(sapply(needle.split, function(x) {
        apply(sapply(x, grepl, haystack, fixed=TRUE), 1, all) + 0
      }), haystack)
}

funAM <- function() {
    Specials <- c(".", "|", "(", ")", "[", "{", "^", "$", "*", "+", "?")
    Patterns <- strsplit(patterns, "", fixed=TRUE)
    out <- vapply(vapply(Patterns, function(x) {
      x <- ifelse(x %in% Specials, paste0("\\", x), x)
      paste0("^", paste0("(?=.*", x, ")", collapse=""))
    }, character(1L)), grepl, logical(length(code)),
    code, perl = TRUE) * 1
    dimnames(out) <- list(code, patterns)
    out
}
```

***Tiny data***

```
haystack <- code <- c("efhikq&*", "efhiku&", "DHIfux", 
                      "DHIJUVXYefhjoq!*", "HIfghv(", "hiIvg")
needle <- patterns <- c("gh", "HI", "&*")

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(funBG(), funAM())
# Unit: microseconds
#     expr     min      lq  median       uq     max neval
#  funBG() 686.509 717.405 741.209 754.3070 977.042   100
#  funAM() 248.062 257.851 265.587 277.5425 651.062   100
```

***Medium data***

```
set.seed(1)
haystack <- code <- sample(code, 1000, replace = TRUE)
microbenchmark(funBG(), funAM())
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#  funBG() 19.859273 20.662812 20.894996 21.856938 36.80115   100
#  funAM()  1.359937  1.403614  1.477143  1.498897  2.78009   100

identical(funBG(), funAM())
# [1] TRUE
```

***Bigger data***

```
haystack <- code <- sample(code, 1e6, replace = TRUE)
system.time(funBG())
#   user  system elapsed 
# 50.372   0.003  53.057 
system.time(funAM())
#  user  system elapsed 
# 1.135   0.000   1.141
```

Comment: +1, very interesting use of lookaheads.  Until this week I'd never seen sequential use of lookahead/lookbehinds, and I see two in three days!  It would never have occurred to me to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution (based on Ananda Mahto's comment):

```
code <- c("efhikq&*", "efhiku&", "DHIfux", "DHIJUVXYefhjoq!*", "HIfghv(", "hiIvg")
patterns <- c("gh", "HI", "&*")

cols <- sapply(patterns, function(x) as.numeric(grepl(x, code, fixed = TRUE)))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(code,cols))
```

Comment: As BrodieG has noted, my original comment doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: I see it now. The implementation of BrodieG is for the combination of `g` and `h`, not for the exact phrase `gh`.